# \listofchanges Option list view gives error

Tags: todonotes, changes

if I use `\listofchanges[style=summary, title={My Summary}]` the summary is printed properly. However, if I use     `\listofchanges[style=list, title={My Summary}]` I get this error message:

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...ofchanges[style=list, title={My Summary}], and it looks also bad.
[image]

I don't quite understand what this problem is. Does anyone have an idea what happened? Here's a comparable MME.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\graphicspath{{Grafics/}}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
    \highlight{test} and some more tests 
    \listofchanges[style=list, title={My Summary}]
\end{document}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the example you provide suppose to give the image that you posted? Because it does not at my end.

Comment: Oh! Interesting, because yes, it does. I use XeLaTex to compile, maybe that is an issue?

Comment: If I run xelatex on it, I get a compilation error. Don't ignore compilation errors. Works fine with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no option but XeLaTex since I require Asian fonts. Any other work around?

Comment: Erh, lualatex should not have any issues with Asian fonts.

Comment: How easy is it to switch the compiler? I need to submit my dissertation very soon, and don't really have time for hiccups.